# Make photo public but keep set/collection private in Flickr

Tags: flickr

I want to make a couple of photos public in a specific set, but when I do that, the set itself becomes visible in my profile. Obviously with just the photos I made public, but I don't want the set to appear at all.

Is there a way to make certain photos public (so they appear in my photostream), but without exposing the set or collection?

Comment: Have you tried adding the specific photos to another set?

Comment: No, I haven't. Let me try that and see what happens.

Comment: Ok, I'd have to take the photo out of the original set... not quite what I was wanting but it will have to do - flickr doesn't have permissions on the set level, so if any pictures in the set are public, it appears under sets. Alternatively, I can just upload the image twice...

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, this is not possible, due to the lack of permissions at the set / collection level in Flickr—if any pictures in a set are public, it appears under your sets (publicly). If the set is in a collection, the collection also appears, with its full mosaic thumbnail, even if those pictures are private.

The only real workaround is to upload the relevant images twice, one public, in a specific public set, and the other private (in it's original set).

Comment: Is this still the case today?